# The volume of spheres in the Sasaki metric

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let  $(M,g)$ be  a $n$ dimensional  Riemannian manifold. The  corresponding Sasaki metric on $TM$ is  denoted by $g_s$. This enable us to measure the volume $\mathcal{A}(S_x)$ of each unit sphere $S_x\subset T_x M,\;x\in M$.(Each $S_x$ inherit the Sasaki metric so it has a natural volum form). The sphere of radius $r$ is denoted by $S^r_x$.

> Under which sufficient and necessary conditions on $(M,g)$ the quantity $\mathcal{A}(S_x)$ is independent of $x\in M$
>
> Under which necessary and sufficient conditions $\mathcal{A}(S^r_x) $ is   a constant multiplier of $r^{n-1}$, for a constant independent of the base point $x\in M$?

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sasaki_metric, the Sasaki metric restricted to each fiber is the standard Euclidean metric.

Comment: @DeaneYang  I am sorry if  my question is  elementary. May  you elaborate the  second point in the linked wikipedia? Does this second point  answer my question?

Comment: @DeaneYang  I think that the second point can be modified to "each vertical space is isometric to the corresponding tangent space", yes? But the base points vary.

Comment: My comment, which is the second point in the wikipedia article, along with a straightforward use of basic definitions and facts from differential and Riemannian geometry answers your question. I think you're able to work out the details yourself.

Comment: @DeaneYang  Thanks for your comment. I think about that.